# Opening a STL file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d

I extracted coordinates of vertices in a STL file and used these simple codes to visualize the 3D model:

```
for i=0:214
 fill3(A(:,i*7+3),A(:,i*7+4),A(:,i*7+5),'b');
 grid on; hold on; alpha(0.3)
end
```

the 3D model is a **sphere-like object** with 214 triangles, but I got this: 
[image]

what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a typo! `fill3` is enough to plot a STL file. Here is the result.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing surface data to `fill3`, just points, so there is no clearly defined triangulation, and it is trying to fill between consecutive vertices (which may be in no particular order).

You can recreate the surface data using a function like `convhull` (if your object is convex), see the below example.

Alternatively, since you have the STL file, you may already have the triangulation data available for use with `trisurf`.

[image: plots]

```matlab
% Create points on a sphere
N = 200;
TH = 2*pi*rand(1,N).';
PH = asin(-1+2*rand(1,N)).';
A = NaN(N,3);
[A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3)] = sph2cart(TH,PH,1);

% Plotting
figure(5); clf

subplot(1,3,1);
plot3(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),'.');
grid on; title( 'plot3' );

subplot(1,3,2);
fill3(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),'b');
grid on; title( 'fill3' );

subplot(1,3,3);
Tri = convhull(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3));
trisurf(Tri,A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),'Facecolor','b');
grid on; title( 'trisurf / convhull' );
```

Comment: If for some reason you don't have the triangulation data available, you could do a Delaunay triangulation https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html

Comment: I need to have exactly what I have in my stl file, the same vertexes. trisurf() uses Delaunay function.

Comment: Right, so you understand that you need the surface data from the STL, not just the vertices? I've not suggested changing your vertices, just defining how they are related. Without adding some kind of [mcve] to your question we don't know what that data looks like.

Comment: my data is not special or complicated. [v1, v2, v3], [v1, v2, v3]...

Comment: You're not indicating that you understand my point, I tried to show it visually with the 3 plots above. take `P1, P2, ..., P6` as six x/y/z points. There are 20 different ways to choose triplets here, and you clearly don't want 20 triangles (connecting every 3 points), so you have to define each *surface* in terms of the three vertices which it is comprised of. You might only want 3 triangles defined by these 6 points! I have done this with `convhull`, but your STL must contain this data in some form.

Comment: It's also unclear in your question how you expect the loop to work, `i` is only incrementing by 1 each time which means you're sharing points as you loop up. Again, without a [mcve] it's literally impossible for us to tell if this is the right thing to do or not (I suspect not).

Comment: stl file is abit explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format) . these files are somehow output of sth like Delaunay function. we have normal vector for each triangle and its vertices. of course vertices can be shared.

Comment: I'm not sure if normal vectors can be of any help. they can show inside or outside of my surface or object... nothing more.

Comment: The description of the format on that wiki clearly shows how the triangles are defined, this is why **your question needs a self contained example**!! We could have removed all of this back and forth if you included on in your question. Your loop isnt doing what you want it to do, try debugging it to see why, creating a [mcve] will help you do this, and help us help you if you include it in the question